# AND statement on same table on values from same field returns 0 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with the following thing: I have a table called custom_fields. Within it there is a field with values like product_id, money_spent. When I do an AND query to get data I get 0 results (even though the conditions are met). This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `users` . * 
FROM  `users` 
LEFT JOIN  `emails` ON  `users`.`id` =  `emails`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `phones` ON  `users`.`id` =  `phones`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `trackers` ON  `users`.`tracker_id` =  `trackers`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `custom_fields` ON  `users`.`id` =  `custom_fields`.`user_id` 
WHERE (
`custom_fields`.`field` =  "product_id"
AND  `custom_fields`.`value` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `custom_fields`.`value` !=  ""
)
AND (
`custom_fields`.`field` =  "payment_value"
)
AND (
`custom_fields`.`value` <50
AND  `custom_fields`.`value` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `custom_fields`.`value` !=  ""
)
AND (
`users`.`tracker_id` =186
)
```

How to solve this problem? I tried to use UNION but it gives different results. Maybe some aliases? I can't do the transposition on this table (meaning: convert each row to a seperate field)

Comment: Give us some example data from the tables that proves "the conditions are met". If you're getting 0 results, it suggests that they're not being met. If you have no AND clauses, do you get results? What happens when you add the AND clauses back one by one?

Comment: You're specifying '`custom_fields`.`field` =  "product_id"' and '`custom_fields`.`field` =  "payment_value"'. They can't both be true.

Comment: For instance I have a client which product_id value is A1 and payment_value value is 40 - so the conditions are met. Without AND I get results for seperate fields. What do you mean by adding AND clauses one by one?

Comment: Paul, so how can I rewrite the query to check if the product_id has  any value AND simultaneously payment value is less than 50 for the user?

Comment: Obviously you don't know exactly what you are doing. You are using DISTINCT, but are not all records in table users distinct? You outer join custom_fields, but how for instance can custom_fields.field` =  "product_id" be true, when there is no record in custom_fields? Then, as Paul already mentioned there can be no record for which field is "product_id" and "payment_value" at the same time. Rather than explaining technically what query you have written, you should tell us what exactly your query is actually supposed to do, i.e. what shall be the query's result.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, I would like to list users, who has some value in  product_id and simultaneously (AND) have value of the payment_value is less than 50. So if for instance user XYZ product_id.value = A1B2 AND payment_value.value = 48 I want the query to list him

Comment: Why do you join the tables emails, phones and trackers at all? Are you simply looking for `select from users where exists (...)` after all?

Comment: You treat value as a number one time (`value < 50`) and as a string another (`value !=  ""`). What datatype it actually. Be aware that type conversions can result in undesired results. For example '' converted to a number would be 0 in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `custom_fields` is a [EAV-style table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (i.e. it has multiple entries per one entity like user, in form of a set [entry type, entry label, entry value]), you need to do multiple `JOIN`s with this table to achieve the desired result.

Try this query instead. It filters users having both: entries in `custom_fields` of type `product_id` and entries of type `payment_value` with value lower than 50:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `users` . * 
FROM  `users` 
LEFT JOIN  `emails` ON  `users`.`id` =  `emails`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `phones` ON  `users`.`id` =  `phones`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `trackers` ON  `users`.`tracker_id` =  `trackers`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `custom_fields` as cf1 ON  `users`.`id` =  cf1.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `custom_fields` as cf2 ON  `users`.`id` =  cf2.`user_id` 
WHERE (
cf1.`field` =  "product_id"
AND  cf1.`value` IS NOT NULL 
AND  cf1.`value` !=  ""
)
AND (
cf2.`field` =  "payment_value"
AND cf2.`value` <50
AND  cf2.`value` IS NOT NULL 
AND  cf2.`value` !=  ""
)
AND (
`users`.`tracker_id` =186
)
```

Comment: -1 from me. You've taken the dubious query and made a minor change just so it works somehow, without pointing the OP to the various issues with the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner care to explain what issues you have in mind?

Comment: I did so in the request comments. The OP just seems to know little about what he/she is actually doing. Just putting together some tables, some criteria, and a distinct keyword (because obviously surprisingly to them there were duplicates in the results), till at last they get (more or less) the desired records.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Is asker's knowing little about it any of my fault?
I understood what he was trying to achieve and corrected his query, without trying to fix what was not broken (i.e. maybe was desired). I did it on purpose, I admit. Aren't you a little too strict about it?..

Comment: Okay, I'll undo my -1. Still I think, when seeing this query, one immediately doubts the OP knows what he/she is doing here, and we should point them to the mistakes made, so as to learn from this how to use SQL properly.

Comment: Point taken, I'll keep it in mind next time. Thx for undoing -1, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

All you seem to want to do is select users for which a product id exists and also a payment value less than 50 exists. So simply use the word EXISTS (that one uses to formulate the task) in your query as well and there are no longer issues with duplicate results. Plus the query is much easier to read, because you use SQL straight-forward.

```
select *
from users
where tracker_id = 186
and exists
(
  select * 
  from custom_fields
  where field = 'product_id' and value is not null
)
and exists
(
  select * 
  from custom_fields
  where field = 'payment_value' and value < 50 -- and value > 0 maybe?
);
```

As you see, quite often you can just put the task in words that can be easily translated into SQL.

Please also read in your request's comment section about problems with your query.

Answer (score 0):

May be can try using self join / or creating aliases of custom_fields table. Try below query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  `users` . * 
    FROM  `users` 
    LEFT JOIN  `emails` ON  `users`.`id` =  `emails`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN  `phones` ON  `users`.`id` =  `phones`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN  `trackers` ON  `users`.`tracker_id` =  `trackers`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN  `custom_fields` cf1 ON  `users`.`id` =  `cf1`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN  `custom_fields` cf2 ON  `users`.`id` =  `cf2`.`user_id` 

   WHERE (
    `cf1`.`field` =  "product_id"
    AND  `cf1`.`value` IS NOT NULL 
    AND  `cf1`.`value` !=  ""
    )
    AND (
    `cf2`.`field` =  "payment_value"
    )
    AND (
    `cf2`.`value` <50
    AND  `cf2`.`value` IS NOT NULL 
    AND  `cf2`.`value` !=  ""
    )
    AND (
    `users`.`tracker_id` =186
    )
```